# Force html table to have eight columns on a single row

Tags: html, css

I have a PHP array that produces four columns per row of a table. 
Is there anyway to force an HTML table to display 8 columns per row?

For example if my output is:

```
<tr>
<td>COL 1</td>
<td>COL 2</td>
<td>COL 3</td>
<td>COL 4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>COL 5</td>
<td>COL 6</td>
<td>COL 7</td>
<td>COL 8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>COL 9</td>
<td>COL 10</td>
<td>COL 11</td>
<td>COL 12</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>COL 13</td>
<td>COL 14</td>
<td>COL 15</td>
<td>COL 16</td>
</tr>
```

And the display looks like:

```
COL 1 COL 2 COL 3 COL 4
COL 5 COL 6 COL 7 COL 8
COL 9 COL 10 COL 11 COL 12
COL 13 COL 14 COL 15 COL 16
```

Is there anyway CSS or HTMl can force the table to display eight columns on a single line before breaking?  So create something like this?

```
COL 1 COL 2 COL 3 COL 4      COL 5 COL 6 COL 7 COL 8
COL 9 COL 10 COL 11 COL 12   COL 13 COL 14 COL 15 COL 16
```

Comment: Do you have code we can work with, or do you want an answer in unicorns?

Comment: @Zoltan Seeing if there is a simpler solution

Comment: Yes: `<tr>
<td>COL 1</td>
<td>COL 2</td>
<td>COL 3</td>
<td>COL 4</td>
<td>COL 5</td>
<td>COL 6</td>
<td>COL 7</td>
<td>COL 8</td>
</tr>` If you want a better answer. Ask a better question.

Comment: It's a good idea to show your PHP code.

Comment: @MadBurn well you obviously didn't read or think about an answer properly because its pretty obvious hes talking about his current html structure but using some sort of styling to make it display differently.

Comment: If data in your 2 rows could also exists as their own columns, then tables probably aren't the appropriate method for displaying it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change your PHP to format it the correct way or use divs and style it accordingly, however if its true tabular data id use tables and fix your PHP to represent what you want.

It really isnt all that difficult in PHP, you could for example just have a counter and when that counter % 2 == 0 then finish the row and start a new one.  Increase the counter accordingly.

**Pseudo code**

*Currently you have something like this.*

```
for($i = 0; $i < numRows; $i++) {
    output a <tr> tag

    output <td> tags and data

    output a closing </tr> tag
}
```

*What you need to do is something like this.*

```
for($i = 0; $i < numRows; $i++)  {
    if($i % 2 == 0)
        output startting <tr> tag

    output some <td> tags with data

    if(($i +1) % 2 == 0)
        output closing <tr> tag
}
```

Alternatley you could just use a boolean flag

```
is_even_row = ture;
for each row {
    if(is_even_row)
        output start tag

    output data for row

    if(not is_even_row)
        output end tag

    is_even_row = not is_even_row
}
```

Comment: @Hope4You Divs are very good, however for true tabular data I would still encourage the use of tables, after all, thats what they are there for.  I would discourage people using tables for laying out a website though obviously.

Comment: @Jon THANKS!  Could you provide a quick example on how to do that in PHP?  I'm a beginner and a reference would help a lot.

Comment: @JonTaylor Maybe you're right, but I completely use divs because it's the more modern, quicker-loading method. It may be harder for some people to use divs, but I personally think it's easier and simpler.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to approach this problem is to fix the PHP that's generating the wrong HTML layout for your purposes, that said, with CSS, there is at least one option:

```
table {
    disply: block;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 1em auto;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

tr {
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

td {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/fwM8M/1/).

There is also a JavaScript solution (if such is available):

```
var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0],
    rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');

for (var i=rows.length - 1; i>=0; i--){
    if (i%2 == 1 && i !== 0){
        var prev = rows[i].previousElementSibling;
        while (rows[i].firstChild){
            prev.appendChild(rows[i].firstChild);
        }
        rows[i].parentNode.removeChild(rows[i]);
    }
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/fwM8M/2/).

Comment: Very neat!  I tried this and it worked well.  I'm going to go with your suggestion though and fix the PHP.  Many thanks for the answer.

Comment: No problem, it's far smarter to correct the generating code (otherwise you'll spend far too much time picking up afterwards).