# Forcing PHP loop to display 8 columns per row

Tags: php, html, css

I have a PHP array that produces four columns per row of a table. I need to modify my php so I have eight columns per row instead of four.

For example.  The current output looks like:

```
COL 1 COL 2 COL 3 COL 4
COL 5 COL 6 COL 7 COL 8
COL 9 COL 10 COL 11 COL 12
COL 13 COL 14 COL 15 COL 16
```

But I need it to look like this:

```
COL 1 COL 2 COL 3 COL 4      COL 5 COL 6 COL 7 COL 8
COL 9 COL 10 COL 11 COL 12   COL 13 COL 14 COL 15 COL 16
```

On a previous question I asked if I could do this via CSS/HTML. It was strongly suggested that I modify my PHP code instead. I received the pseudo code to do this, but I'm having trouble getting it to work.  The logic is as follows:

```
if($counter % 2 == 0)
    output startting <tr> tag

output the four <td> tags with data

if(($counter +1) % 2 == 0)
    output closing <tr> tag
```

Here is my current code:

```
            <form>
            <table>
                <?php $counter = 0;
                while ($counter < 20) : 
                $item = $set[$counter]
                                    if($counter % 2 == 0) ?>
                    <tr class="q<?php echo $counter; ?>">                   
                        <td><a class="question" href="<?php echo $item['qurl'] ?>');"><?php echo $item['q'] ?></a></td>
                        <td><input class="a1" type="text" name="a1" maxlength="3" size="3" /></td>
                        <td><input class="a2" type="text" name="a2" maxlength="3" size="3" /></td>
                        <td><input class="submit submit-<?php echo $counter; ?>" type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
                                    <?php if(($counter +1) % 2 == 0) ?>
                    </tr>
                <?php $counter++; ?>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </table>
                            </form>
```

I'm a beginner so please excuse my novice attempt.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should update your original question rather than creating a new one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11587360/force-html-table-to-have-eight-columns-on-a-single-row/11587391#11587391

Comment: Very sorry.  I'm new here.  My previous question was about editing HTML/CSS so I thought I should create a new one for the PHP.

Comment: Yeah I guess, its not really the same question but continues on from what you were talking about earlier, dont know what SO rules are on that.

Comment: Ok, do you think I should delete this and just update my other question? Don't want to break any rules.

Comment: leave it for now, if a mod thinks its inappropriate hell close it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should really check out the [syntax for the PHP if statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) .

```
$counter = 0;
while ($counter < count($set)) : 
    $item = $set[$counter];
    if($counter % 2 == 0): ?>
        <tr class="q<?php echo $counter; ?>">                   
    <?php endif;?>
            <td><a class="question" href="javascript:soundManager.play('<?php echo $item['qurl'] ?>','audio/part2/type1/type1_<?php echo $item['qurl'] ?>.mp3');"><?php echo $item['q'] ?></a></td>
            <td><input class="a1" type="text" name="a1" maxlength="3" size="3" /></td>
            <td><input class="a2" type="text" name="a2" maxlength="3" size="3" /></td>
            <td><input class="submit submit-<?php echo $counter; ?>" type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
    <?php if(($counter +1) % 2 == 0): ?>
        </tr>
    <?php endif;?>
    <?php $counter++; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php if(($counter +1) % 2 == 0): ?>
    </tr>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use with `array_chunk()` to split array to small array and print this..

```
<table>
<?php foreach (array_chunk($set, 2) as $row_set): ?>
  <tr>
  <?php foreach ($row_set as $item_set): ?>
    <td><?php echo $item_set['qurl']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $item_set['q']; ?></td>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
</table>
```

Good luck :)

Comment: A much better solution IMHO. The first suggestion isn't nearly as elegant as this one!